# PHP Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, errordocument

Moved from hosting site NameCheap to the server and one of the paths /plan was in PHP format, after installing all the files in CPanel to the site, stopped going to this path writing:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Can anyone help with this?

I looked up the details, they say you need to change the .htaccess, but I don't understand which one and how.I looked up the details, they say you need to change the .htaccess, but I don't understand which one and how
I have two of them, one is in the index.html folder and the other is in the Form folder

Comment: We're not going to be able to help much unless you at least show us the  files in question. Presumably your old server had the right setup - did you copy everything from there into a backup?